# How to use awk to add missing lines in line groups

Tags: awk

hi everyone and sorry for the simple question, i have a list of text files with pc specs i'm trying to extract data from. Using:

```
awk '/Disk\:/ && !/USB/ ||FNR==1 {c++;if(FNR==1)c=0;print c " " $0}'  *.txt > file
```

I can extract the number and model of disk per system as follows

```
0 SYSTEM
1 Disk: ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-0 SCSI Disk Device (465,8 GB)
0 SYSTEM
1 Disk: ST3160815AS (149,0 GB)
0 SYSTEM
1 Disk: WDC WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0 (465,8 GB)
2 Disk: WDC WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0 (465,8 GB)
3 Disk: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 (3,6 TB)
```

Each system can have up to four disks and what I'm trying to do is add the missing lines so I can transform the file into a CSV down the road. The required output would be the following:

```
0 SYSTEM
1 Disk: ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-0 SCSI Disk Device (465,8 GB)
2 Disk: NO DISK
3 Disk: NO DISK
4 Disk: NO DISK
0 SYSTEM
1 Disk: ST3160815AS (149,0 GB)
2 Disk: NO DISK
3 Disk: NO DISK
4 Disk: NO DISK
0 SYSTEM
1 Disk: WDC WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0 (465,8 GB)
2 Disk: WDC WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0 (465,8 GB)
3 Disk: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 (3,6 TB)
4 Disk: NO DISK
```

I've searched the forums and found both examples that add missing lines and group lines by n, but haven't managed to combine the two somehow.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an update to your original script. It keeps the same logic with a small update.

```
awk '(NR!=1) && (FNR==1) { for(c++;c<=4;++c) { print c" Disk: NODISK" }}
     (FNR==1) { c=0; print c,$0 }
     /Disk\:/ && !/USB/ { print ++c,$0 }
     END{ for(c++;c<=4;++c) { print c" Disk: NODISK" }}' *txt
```

- The first line does: *If we enter a new file but not the first file, print the missing disks*
- The second line does: *If we enter a new file, set `c=0` and print the line (this prints `0 SYSTEM`)*
- The last line does: *If the line contains the word `DISK` but not the word `USB`, increment `c` and print the line.*
- When we finish, *print the missing disks for the last file*

Comment: the first one was close but not displaying the last NO DISK lines, this one works like a charm! thank you for the explanation as well.